# A convention for indicating whether an HTML element is referenced from JS code

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

This is a follow-up question for [In jQuery is it a bad idea to use name=X for all selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051921/in-jquery-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-name-x-for-all-selectors)

---

I am using Backbone and decided that I wanted a way to differentiate between HTML elements that were bound and those that were not.

So I would write (in HAML):

```
.container
  .title(name='title')
  .separator
```

As you can see it's clear that the dynamic element is title.

The reason for this was so I could mess around with the style and rename classes without worrying about breaking the app. It also means in the template I can tell what the dynamic elements are without needing to go back and forth with the Backbone View.

My question now is, **without using the [name] selector, does anyone have a code convention to keep track of which HTML elements are referenced from JS**.

I have considering:

- Using a common prefix on class names (e.g. `class=bind-title`)
- Using some sort of custom HTML element (

Thanks!

---

FYI: I'm using CoffeeScript, Backbone and haml_coffee templates.

---

Updated jsperf to test all suggestions:

http://jsperf.com/class-or-name-attr-lookup/3

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a class to indicate that it is dynamic.
I'm not sure if you are aware of this but you can have multiple classes on one element. Like so:

```
.container
  .dynamic.title(name='title')
  .separator
```

This works in [traditional HAML](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html) but I have not tried it with `haml-coffee`. If it doesn't work, you might have to specify the class like `.title{:class => "dynamic"}(name='title')`.

I prefer this over a prefix on the class name because it's more semantically meaningful, which is how HTML should be used.

Comment: Thanks sirhc. This is the approach I have settled with, I'm going to use .bind because its a little shorter.

Comment: It doesn't stand out that much though. I was hoping there might be some HTML element that I could use. I just read on another SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5) that it is possible to use your own HTML tags too.

Comment: However, custom tags should *only* be used when you are creating a *new element*. This means is that this element has cannot be described by any other form of HTML. You are classifying certain *existing elements* as dynamic. Hence, I would not recommend the use of a custom tag.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `data-view` attribute on elements being set when rendering my Views.

This helps me to then [show a tooltip](https://github.com/radekstepan/backbone.js-which-view) in a browser window when I hover over View(s).

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid using attributes as selectors because of the associated performance penalty. I considered using something like `data-bind` just as an indication in the source that it is bound and then only reference it by its classname, but it seems wrong.

Also, I'm not actually requiring a way of referencing a view from an element, more often the other way round - modifying an element from a view.